# How do I loop through a Pandas DataFrame and call a function on each cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the following code to rate text

```
import textstat
import pandas as pd

test_data = ("""Jonathan pushed back the big iron pot and stood up.
There were no bears. But up the path came his father, carrying his gun. And with
him were Jonathan's Uncle James and his Uncle Samuel, his Uncle John and his
Uncle Peter. Jonathan had never in all his life been so glad to see the uncles.
"Jonathan!'" said his father, "what a fright you have given us! Where have you
been all this time?" """)

textstat.flesch_reading_ease(test_data)
```

Gives a score of 100.48 (very easy to read)

I have a csv with 'Title' and 'Text' columns. 
I want to loop through each row and use the textstat.flesch_reading_ease function on each cell with of the 'Text' column.

However, I just can't seem to get this right.

```
import textstat 
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv('my_list_of_texts.csv')


for i, j in csv.iterrows():
     a = textstat.flesch_reading_ease(j)
     print(a)
```

This gives me the error 
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by placing textstat.flesch_reading_ease in it's own function and removing NaNs from the series.

```
def readability_score(text):
    s = textstat.automated_readability_index(text)
    return s

csv = csv.dropna()
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply is here to do the job in pandas DataFrame and Series.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

And you can find some examples here :

https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_apply_operations_to_dataframes/

Answer (score 1):

Use [Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html):

```
csv['Text'].apply(textstat.flesch_reading_ease)
```

Comment: With this I get a 'TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable' - the problem is passing in the textstat.flesch_reading_ease function. Any ideas how to get around this?